# slide em js não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Estou com o seguinte problema possuo 3 imagens com os seguintes nomes e extensões:

```
f1.jpg
f2.jpg
f3.jpg
```

e estou fazendo um slide com JS porem a primeira imagem e carregada corretamente porem quando eu clico no botão próximo ela falha a imagem seguinte não aparece segue o código:

o JS:

```
<script language="javascript">

        function preload(){
            imgs = Array('f1.jpg','f2.jpg','f3.jpg');
            imgQtde = imgs.length;
            for(i = 0;1<imgQtde;i++){
                var preloadimg = new image();
                preloadimg.src = imgs[i];
            }
        }

        function iniciaSlider(){
            preload();
            max = 3;
            min = 1;
            fi = 1;
            tr=true;
            carregafoto("images/slide/f1.jpg");
            document.getElementById("moldura").addEventListener("transitionend",fimTr);
        }

        function fimTr(){
            tr = true;
        }

        function carregafoto(foto){
            document.getElementById("moldura").style.backgroundImage = "URL("+foto+")";
        }

        function prox(){
            if(tr){
                tr = false;
                fi++;
                if (fi>max){
                    fi = min;
                }
                carregafoto("f"+fi+ ".jpg");    
            }
        }

        function ant(){
            if(tr){
                tr = false;
                fi--;
                if (fi<min){
                    fi = max;
                }
                carregafoto("f"+fi+ ".jpg");    
            }
        }
    </script>
```

o HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="anterior" onclick="ant()" />
<input type="button" value="proximo" onclick="prox()" />
```

O CSS:

```
#moldura{
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #eee;
    transition:background-image 2s;
    background-size: 100% 100%; 

}
```

onde estou errando já olhei e refiz varias veses mais não funciona

```css
#moldura {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: background-image 2s;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>DEVDREAM</title>
  <meta name="" charset="UFT-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
    function preload() {
      imgs = Array('f1.jpg', 'f2.jpg', 'f3.jpg');
      imgQtde = imgs.length;
      for (i = 0; 1 < imgQtde; i++) {
        var preloadimg = new image();
        preloadimg.src = imgs[i];
      }
    }

    function iniciaSlider() {
      preload();
      max = 3;
      min = 1;
      fi = 1;
      tr = true;
      carregafoto("images/slide/f1.jpg");
      document.getElementById("moldura").addEventListener("transitionend", fimTr);
    }

    function fimTr() {
      tr = true;
    }

    function carregafoto(foto) {
      document.getElementById("moldura").style.backgroundImage = "URL(" + foto + ")";
    }

    function prox() {
      if (tr) {
        tr = false;
        fi++;
        if (fi > max) {
          fi = min;
        }
        carregafoto("f" + fi + ".jpg");
      }
    }

    function ant() {
      if (tr) {
        tr = false;
        fi--;
        if (fi < min) {
          fi = max;
        }
        carregafoto("f" + fi + ".jpg");
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="iniciaSlider()">
  <header>
    <div id="moldura"></div>
    <input type="button" value="anterior" onclick="ant()" />
    <input type="button" value="proximo" onclick="prox()" />
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Se você puder colar o html, javascript e css no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), salvar e postar o link na pergunta vai facilitar bastante a análise e teste do seu código!

Comment: ok so um instante

Comment: @DanielDutra coloquei ja amigo porem so nao sei como linkar as imagens nesse jsfiddle

Comment: Esta dando erro nesse  if (tr) {} só deixar ele publico :)

Comment: Faz sentido, esse `tr` está sendo usado no código todo, mas não vejo ele sendo declarado fora de um método...

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi o erro está aqui:

```
for(i = 0;1<imgQtde;i++){
   var preloadimg = new image();
   preloadimg.src = imgs[i];
}
```

No `FOR` você disse que `I == 0`; na próxima condição do seu `FOR` você colocou o 1 e não o `I`,
O correto é: `(i = 0; i < imgQtde; i++)`